# Spring singleton bean lifecycle

Tags: spring

I was wondering how the lifecycle of a singleton bean (annotated with `@Scope(value="singleton")`) in Spring is exactly defined.

Specifically, is it guaranteed that within the same `ApplicationContext` consecutive lookups of that bean return the same bean object instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the definition of `singleton` scope: only one instance returned by every call to `getBean()`. Note that non-lazy `singleton` is the default scope in Spring.

Also if singleton is defined as lazy and no other non-lazy bean references it, it will be created during first explicit lookup.

*EDIT*: To answer your comment: occasionally you might discover that your singleton is created twice. Take this bean as an example:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class Singleton {
    public Singleton() {
        System.out.println("Created: " + this.getClass());
    }
}
```

Even though this is a singleton, your program might produce the following output:

```
Created: class com.example.Singleton
Created: class com.example.Singleton$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f8ccc422
```

Constructor has been called twice - once for the original class and second time for the class created by CGLIB to implement proxying on a class without any interfaces. To preserve `Singleton` public interface, the class generated by CGLIB must subclass from the original class. This way CGLIB class might be used where `Singleton` was expected (polymorphism). But subclass *must* call the base class constructor, hence two constructor calls.

But don't worry, the CGLIB-generated class is just a stub that redirects all the calls to a "normal" bean, applying AOP stuff in the meantime.

Comment: Hm... That's weird. While your response confirms my expectations, I am sporadically seeing two instances of a given singleton bean instance (under yet unknown conditions).

Comment: There are several possibilities: you have two application contexts, both picking up the same class (often found in Spring MVC applications, where parent context unnecessarily creates duplicated controllers); I will explain second reason in my answer.