# Spring @PreDestroy and @PostConstruct annotations

Tags: spring, singleton

I am trying to start and stop a quartz scheduler in a spring singleton bean .But postconstruct is getting called two times and predestroy is not called at all . [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681907/spring-singleton-bean-lifecycle)  link says that because of proxying it natural to be called twice but this is causing exception in the postconstruct method . I only want the postConstruct to be called once after the singleton bean is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a  contextloader listener and change web.xml listener .So I can initialize bean only one times.

```
 <listener>
        <listener-class>
              CustomContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

public class CustomContextLoaderListener  extends  
                        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener{
     Scheduler scheduler;

    @Override
     public void contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent event) {
             try{
             super.contextInitialized(event);
             this.scheduler= WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext()).getBean(Scheduler.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event){

          super.contextDestroyed(event);
          scheduler.stopSchedulers();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this using an [init-method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-nature) or try implementing the initializing bean . These provide alternative approaches to postConstruct .

When the spring beans are unloaded i.e , when the container is shut down or the close() method in [ConfigurableApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html) method gets called through some other means, the preDestroy is invoked.

Comment: init-metod also called two times